# Hex to unicode Logic

Tags: unicode, logic

suppose I have been given a hex 416f1c7918f83a4f1922d86df5e78348
how does my program know how to convert this to unicode? 
since I dont see how my program split this number into unicode.

Comment: Hexadecimals are really base 16 numbers 0 - 15. Where a = 10, b = 11, c = 12, d = 13, e = 14, f = 15. What's your question? Why do you want this to be unicode? A String, or numeric base 10 representation?

Comment: Show the unicode result you get. What program are you using?

Comment: "my program"...what language?  What have you tried?  It doesn't look like any common encoding of Unicode.  What's the expected result?

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the encoding. If it's UTF-8, then implement a UTF-8 decoding algorithm. If it's Unicode 16, then you need to find out if it's big-endian or little-endian, then implement a Unicode 16 decoding algorithm. If it's Big5, etc.